# Building Gstreamer Code?

Tags: makefile, gstreamer, autoconf, automake

I wanted to know why autoconf and automake (auto tools) are used to Build the Gstreamer(and odes like gstramer).
These I suppose are used to generate the Makefiles which then can be used by simply running make command.
What are makefile.am and configure.ac files .

Rgds,
Softy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `Makefile.am` is an Automake script shorthand for writing makefiles. It's processed by Automake to generate `Makefile.in`. It's easier to use Automake language to specify dependencies and standard targets required by the GNU Build System.
- `Makefile.in` is a makefile that is missing platform-dependent code. See below.
- `configure.ac` is a file, written in the M4 macro language. It is processed by Autoconf to generate a shell script called `configure`. It is much easier and less error-prone to write `configure.ac` than writing a 200k shell script.
- `configure` is a shell script that checks whether your platform supports all sorts of portable and nonportable features. It generates a whole bunch of files. It can also put platform-dependent and system-dependent code into files (usually ending with `*.in`), transforming them into the same file without the `.in` extension. Specifically, it generates `Makefile` from `Makefile.in`.

The flow diagram on [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automake) may be helpful.